# According to Disney, where during "Beauty and the Beast" do the sequels take place?

Tags: disney, sequel, beauty-and-the-beast

A common complaint about the *Beauty and the Beast* sequels (*[Belle's Magical World](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Belle%27s_Magical_World)* and *[The Enchanted Christmas](http://Beauty%20and%20the%20Beast:%20The%20Enchanted%20Christmas)*) is that they mess with the continuity of the film.

According to Disney, when during the original films do the two DisneyToon sequels take place?

Comment: You might want to add that Belle's Magical World is a series of short cartoons (a failed TV pilot) rather than a single show

Comment: Is there any good reason to assume that they aren't set when they appear to be set, during the winter and spring?

Comment: @Valorum: Surprisingly, I think this is a fair question.  The original had some serious timeline issues w.r.t. Maurice, Gaston, and the villagers.  It's not unreasonable to be confused about exactly how long Belle was in the castle.

Comment: @Kevin - This isn't the first time (nor will it be the last) that Disney has done an "out of continuity" show set inside a film. [Hercules The Animated Series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hercules_(1998_TV_series)) was set *during* the [training sequence](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OtTmR_v6pz4) but also contained multiple interactions between Hercules and Hades (who in the film was unaware of his existence at this point).

Comment: @Valorum Not to mention "The Emperor's New School." But am not aware of them doing this with a movie.

Comment: I'm not sure this is answerable beyond the comment above. Disney (and other filmmakers) sometimes do 'out-of-continuity-spin-offs'. [Many of these](http://disney.wikia.com/wiki/Special:Search?search=TV+Series+based+off+films) are set in the *same fictional universe* but often **directly contradict the known continuity of the original film** with no explanation offered.

Comment: I suspect that in the case of Enchanted Christmas, their desire to do a Christmas movie completely steamrolled any worry of continuity issues.But it really does open up the possible timeline of the film - it was temperate and pleasant when her time in the castle starts, and again when it ends.  This implies that she was there right through the winter, starting in the fall and ending in the spring.

Comment: @VBartilucci care to expand your comment into an answer?

Answer (score 3):

I suspect that in the case of Enchanted Christmas, their desire to do a Christmas movie completely steamrolled any worry of continuity issues.

But it really does open up the possible timeline of the film - it was temperate and pleasant when her time in the castle starts, and again when it ends. This implies that she was there right through the winter, starting in the fall and ending in the spring. So we're looking at anywhere between four to six months, including that winter.

So the answer to the question would be that **Enchanted Christmas happens at some point during her stay at the Prince's domicile**, if you adjust when that stay took place, and its length.

[Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Belle%27s_Magical_World) lists the events of Magical world as "after Christmas but before the fight with Gaston" so it would take place after Enchanted Christmas